# How can I get my main class returned?

Tags: java

This main class is initialized by the Bukkit framework and cannot be initialized again.

```
public class Demo extends JavaPlugin {
    public void onEnable() {

    }
}
```

How do I access its unique instance from other classes?

```
public class CoolDown extends BukkitRunnable {
    public CoolDown(Demo mainClass, int time) {

    }
    public void run() {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If you want to use the OOP way:**
In your `CoolDown` class, have a field with the type of `Demo` (or your JavaPlugin-extending class). You may also create any other fields you will pass in the constructor here.

```
private final Demo plugin;
private int time;
```

Then instantiate the fields using the CoolDown's constructor

```
public CoolDown(Demo plugin, int time) {
    this.plugin = plugin;
    this.time = time;
}
```

Now you can use the `plugin` field for your needs. Example:

```
public void run() {
    plugin.fooBar();
}
```

***If you want to use the Static Programming way*** (not recommended, you are in a OOP language being Java!): In your `Demo` class, have a public, static field of type `Demo`, without any value (this is after the class decleration, by the way).

```
public static Demo instance;
```

In your plugin's enable method (I suggest to put this at the very first line of the method invokation):

```
instance = this;
```

Then you can use, in your `CoolDown`'s `run()` method invokation:

```
Demo.instance.fooBar();
```

Once again, I do not suggest using static programming in Java. It's a lazy and bad practice in general.

Here is a full example, in your case, in OOP programming:

```
public class Demo extends JavaPlugin {
    public void onEnable() {
        Bukkit.getScheduler.scheduleMyEpicCooldown(new CoolDown(this, time), time);
    }
}


public class CoolDown extends BukkitRunnable {
    private final Demo plugin;
    private int time;

    public CoolDown(Demo plugin, int time) {
        this.plugin = plugin;
        this.time = time;
    } 

    public void run() {
        plugin.fooBar();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to re-invent the [Singleton Pattern](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/singleton_pattern.htm).

```
public class Demo extends JavaPlugin {
    private static Demo instance;
    public Demo() {
        instance = this;
    }
    public static Demo getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
    @Override
    public void onEnable() {

    }
}
```

To access:

```
public class Cooldown extends BukkitRunnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Plugin main = Demo.getInstance();
        main.getServer().broadcastMessage("No need to have the main instance as member variable on each class.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Noteworthy statement is that when a class requires the instance, it can simply invoke the public `Demo.getInstance()` method. This global access point removes the need for reinitialization.

Comment: @Unihedron Added in the answer.